# Deep linking for 3 levels in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to retrieve the entire single object hierarchy from the database as a JSON. I decided to use MongoDB with its `$lookup` support.

So I have three collections:

**1. Restaurants**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
    "name" : "KFC",
    "city" : "Lahore",
    "area" : "Johar town",
    "min_order" : "500",
    "del_time" : "1 hour",
    "del_fees" : "5",
    "pre_order" : "no",
    "rating_star" : "0",
    "rating_no" : 0,
    "status" : "1",
    "working_hours" : {
        "monday" : "2pm 6am",
        "tuesday" : "6am 8pm",
        "wednesday" : "9pm 5pm",
        "thursday" : "3pm 6pm",
        "friday" : "1pm 9pm",
        "saturday" : "4pm 5pm",
        "sunday" : "4pm 8pm"
    },
    "cuisines" : [
        "fast food, pizza"
    ],
    "payments" : [
        "cash,credit card,paypal"
    ]
}
```

**2. categories**

```
"categories" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c6a05421c8b8d04443aa7e"),
        "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
        "name" : "Breakfast",
        "category_id" : "1",
        "__v" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c6a06021c8b8d04443aa7f"),
        "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
        "name" : "Special",
        "category_id" : "2",
        "__v" : 0
    }
]
```

**3. items**

```
"items" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57c6da8cc8d053e8310dfe65"),
                "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
                "category_id" : ObjectId("57c6a05421c8b8d04443aa7e"),
                "name" : "Water",
                "price" : "55",
                "rating" : "0",
                "__v" : 0
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57c6da96c8d053e8310dfe66"),
                "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
                "category_id" : ObjectId("57c6a05421c8b8d04443aa7e"),
                "name" : "Milk",
                "price" : "55",
                "rating" : "0",
                "__v" : 0
            }
        ]
```

I want an output in Json response like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
    "name" : "KFC",
    "city" : "Lahore",
    "area" : "Johar town",
    "min_order" : "500",
    "del_time" : "1 hour",
    "del_fees" : "5",
    "pre_order" : "no",
    "rating_star" : "0",
    "rating_no" : 0,
    "status" : "1",
    "working_hours" : {
        "monday" : "2pm 6am",
        "tuesday" : "6am 8pm",
        "wednesday" : "9pm 5pm",
        "thursday" : "3pm 6pm",
        "friday" : "1pm 9pm",
        "saturday" : "4pm 5pm",
        "sunday" : "4pm 8pm"
    },
    "cuisines" : [
        "fast food, pizza"
    ],
    "payments" : [
        "cash,credit card,paypal"
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "categories" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c6a05421c8b8d04443aa7e"),
        "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
        "name" : "Breakfast",
        "category_id" : "1",
        "__v" : 0,
        "items" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57c6da8cc8d053e8310dfe65"),
                "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
                "category_id" : ObjectId("57c6a05421c8b8d04443aa7e"),
                "name" : "Water",
                "price" : "55",
                "rating" : "0",
                "__v" : 0
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57c6da96c8d053e8310dfe66"),
                "restaurant_id" : ObjectId("57c6a02021c8b8d04443aa7c"),
                "category_id" : ObjectId("57c6a05421c8b8d04443aa7e"),
                "name" : "Milk",
                "price" : "55",
                "rating" : "0",
                "__v" : 0
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Still, I'm doing like this

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "categories",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "restaurant_id",
        as: "categories"
    }
}])
```

It's working fine for `Restaurants` and `categories` but how I do it for each categories item that I have in `categories`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following aggregation pipeline, bearing in mind that you'd need to do an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operation on the created lookup array in order for the next **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operation to apply:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categories",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "restaurant_id",
            "as": "categories"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$categories" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "items",
            "localField": "categories._id",
            "foreignField": "category_id",
            "as": "categories.items"
        }
    }
 ])
```

Comment: i also did it like that but issue in this is now one restaurant all categories have  different object with restaurant and other details but i want it one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's directly possible.  Per the [documentation on $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array):

> If your localField is an array and you’d like to match the elements
>   inside it against a foreignField which is a single element, you’ll
>   need to $unwind the array as one stage of the aggregation pipeline.

So, basically you need to $unwind your categories array in order to look up items.  But then you can get creative as far as piecing it back together.

For example, this gets close to what you want:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "categories",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "restaurant_id",
        as: "categories"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$categories"
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "items",
        localField: "categories._id",
        foreignField: "category_id",
        as: "items"
    }
},
{
    $project:{
        category: {
            elem: "$categories",
            items: "$items"
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        categories: {$addToSet: "$category"}
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "restaurants",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "restaurant"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$restaurant"
},
{
    $project: {
        _id:false,
        restaurant_id:"$_id",
        categories:true,
        restaurant_data:"$restaurant"
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: it's not showing the result like that i mentioned above in the question. any how thank you wake for response

Comment: Right, this answer isn't meant to produce the exact result.  But it should get you all of the same data with the same hierarchy: Restaurant -> Categories -> Items

Comment: Yes it's showing like that Wake. it's nice. but can you please also tell me how can i delete the _id object() restaurant rename it like that restaurant_id

Comment: If I understand what you mean, check the additional `$project` stage I added to the end.

Comment: Yes it's like that i want but in restaurant data i have "_id" : ObjectId("57c6a03621c8b8d04443aa7d") i want to delete it and all other i have in categories or in items. how i can do it. Wake your query helped me lot thanks for it kindly also solve my this issue